# specify elasticsearch index alias in template file

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I want to create index alias in template file, I have specified index name as "test_2017_12_02" in logstash conf file, my template is as below

```
"aliases" : {"test_2017_12_02" : "test"}
```

but not working, the index getting created without alias

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Dev Tools in kibana of elasticsearch.

```
POST /_aliases
{
    "actions" : [
        { "add" : { "index" : "test_2017_12_02", "alias" : "test" } }
    ]
}
```

ref: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-aliases.html

Comment: To create alias I can do it using  elastic search head plugin and from UI I can do . But I want to specify it in template file, so that we don't do anything manually.